# how to specify height for divs?

Tags: css

I want to specify fixed height for first two divs and percentage values for next two divs.

The last div should occupy all the space (to the bottom of the browser window) left out by the former divs. how do I achieve this in css..?

Here is my css+html.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
<title>One Hundred Percent height divs</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
html
{
height:100%;
}

body 
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
}
header
{
height:20px;
width:100%;
background-color:red;
}
.container2
{
height:40px;
width:100%;
background-color:#11ccdd;
}
.container3
{
height:35%;
width:100%;
background-color:#bacdef;
}
.subcontainer1
{
float:left;
height:35%;
width:50%;
background-color:#569895;
}
.subcontainer2
{
float:left;
height:35%;
width:50%;
background-color:#dbc462;
}
.container4
{
width:100%;
background-color:#aaaadd;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<header>
header
</header>

<div class="ClearAll"></div> 
<div class="container2">
container2
</div>
<div class="ClearAll"></div>

<div class="container3">
<div class="subcontainer1">
subcontainer1
</div>
 <div class="subcontainer2">
subcontainer2
</div>
</div>

<div class="ClearAll"></div>


<div class="container4">
container4


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to mention the pixels values of width for first two divs as I wrote here.
the third container has percentage value of width. the fourth container should occupy the rest of the space(screen size) left out by other three divs. how can I do that ?

Comment: I can't visualize what you want. Do you have any HTML to start with? What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: What divs? I don't see any divs! Divs, Hello! Where are you? _Please post your code, we're not psychic!_

Comment: and how are the divs supposed to be laid out? What's the total space you want to occupy? The screen height? A fixed pixel height? What's your current HTML+CSS? Please add details before expecting an answer.

Comment: here is my codings which contain html+css.

Comment: @mingos he posted it on another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967078/how-to-specify-height-for-divs I'm editing now

Comment: @priya when you want to add more information you should use the edit link you have on this question since you just started a new question, I have tried to merge both, please tell me if the question is complete this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using CSS. You could do some hacks to achieve the same effect, depending on what you want to do, but you didn't really mention *why* you need it to be done that way.

For complicated layouts that are designed to *fill up* the screen in any way, there's a pretty smart jquery plugin called masonry that helps you with that, if you want to take a look.

http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/

Comment: I want to give it with pure css  without any javascript or jquery... is there anyother options..?

Comment: No. Not really. You could do some hack to achieve the same effect, but it would not be by using two divs on top and one below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this JQuery script:

```
function resizeContainer() {
    var screenHeight = $(window).height();
    var allElements = $('header').height() + $('.container2').height() + $('.container3').height();
    var container4Height = screenHeight - allElements;
    $('.container4').css({
        'height': container4Height
    });
}

resizeContainer();

$(window).resize(resizeContainer);
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/NSh35/2/

This CANNOT be done in CSS and look 100% perfect

Comment: thanksfor ur code. But am 0 in javascript. I dono how to bind that javascript with my code. Can u help me?

Comment: You need to include JQuery in the `<head>` of your document by pasting this in: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`